# How to verify that all required included files exist on startup

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Does anybody still work with Classic ASP VBScript and know if it is possible to verify on startup that all included files exist?  This is a large project and requires some refactoring but before moving files into subfolders I'd like to have some test in place that ensures that all the includes are still pointing to the correct files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not something I've ever tried and here's why

In Classic ASP you can have two types of `#include` SSI directives;

1. Relative path includes, which their path from the current directory.

   ```
   <!-- #include file = "subfolder/file.asp" -->
   ```
2. Virtual path includes, which take their path from the Root of the containing Web Application.

   ```
   <!-- #include virtual = "/toplevelfolder/subfolder/file.asp" -->
   ```

If you have `Enable Parent Paths` set in your Web Application you can also use `../` to traverse parent folders when using `#include file`.

With all this in mind, think about what you would have to do for a minute.

First you need to identify all the `#include` directives which you could probably do using a loop to iterate through your Web Application and find the `.asp` files for example and then use a regular expression to pull out the path. However there are complications.

1. You would have to distinguish both `file` and `virtual` types of `#include`
2. Workout a way to translate both types of path, possibly using `GetAbsolutePathName()` and verify the files existence.
3. `virtual` includes can also point to virtual directories that only exist in IIS and that point to another physical location *(doesn't have to be inside the folder structures of the Web Application)*. This is probably the biggest complication in all honesty.